# Is there a way to check if a custom setting already defined in Postgress

Tags: postgresql

I am using set session postgres command inside a nodejs app to be used later inside a table trigger in postgres. Is there a way to check if the setting exists before using it inside the trigger? I tried to find a solution on the net but was not able to find any for it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_update_notify() RETURNS trigger AS $$
someVar VARCHAR(8000)
...
--if setting_1 not found it throws error. I want to put a check here to avoid 
-- that!
SELECT current_setting('setting_1') INTO someVar;
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant parts of the database-side code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the two-paremeter form of [`current_setting`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET).

If the second argument is `TRUE`, you won't get an error if the configuration parameter is not defined.

Comment: Thanks! not sure why I missed it in the original doco.